# concrt.lib missing when compiling with Visual Studo for OneCore

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10-iot-core, ppl

I'm trying to compile my project for Windows Onecore (IOT), with `onecoreuap.lib` using  `$(VC_LibraryPath_VC_x64_OneCore)` e.g (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\onecore\x64`) instead of `VC_Library_Path`

I have `#include <concrt.h>` in my code.

When I build it I get:

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'concrtd.lib'

I've checked, the (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\onecore\x64`), this folder does not contain `concrt.lib` but contains `libconcrt.lib`

I do not explicitly specify `concrt.lib` in the Linker properties

According to Microsoft documentation this library available for onecore (IOT)

How can I use `concrt` (PPL) library with Windows onecore (IOT) projects?

Answer (score 1):

I can find the lib in folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib`. You may try to add the path into library paths. If you can not find the folder, i suspect the installation of visual studio is wrong.Please refer to this topic:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/2afadea2-0207-4941-83c7-d3a898d7ccd7/after-adding-header-include-ltconcurrentqueuehgt-linker-displays-error-link-fatal-error?forum=vcgeneral